# comboBox1.SelectedIndex = value; does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

I am trying to set the value of the comboBox1.SelectedIndex to the index of an item that exists in the comboBox1.Items collection.

```
int selectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(stringValue);
```

The resulting value of selectedIndex is 0 (>= 0), which means that the stringValue was found in the comboBox1.Items collection.

Notwithstanding, the comboBox1.SelectedIndex remains -1.

Comment: And you set comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 before reading back comboBox1.SelectedIndex?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter After I received the value 0 for the selectedIndex, I have the statement: comboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex; but here the comboBox1.SelectedIndex remains -1.

Comment: Can you please read comboBox1.SelectedIndex immediately after setting it?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter As I stated above, I set the value of comboBox1.SelectedIndex in the statement: comboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex; but here the comboBox1.SelectedIndex remains -1.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you showed your real code instead of just quoting one line and merely describing the rest.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter I read the value immediately, using the debugging F11 (checking line by line). The application is verry large, so it is not possible to show all of it. In other places, the same statements work.

Comment: There is one case where the behaviour of the combo box is exactly as you describe: if the Items collection is empty and stringValue is an empty string. FindStringExact may then indeed return 0 but setting the selection will of course not work. Can you exclude that you ran into this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246714/discussion-between-user2102327-and-klaus-gutter).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the expression you're looking for should be:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(stringValue);`
```

Assigning `int selectedIndex` as shown in your post doesn't actually *do* anything other than set a local variable named `selectedIndex` to `0`. In other words, it's correct the way you have in the *title* of your question but incorrect in the *body*. Make sure you're using the right one when you go to make the assignment in your code.

Comment: I do not see the difference between this statement and the statement I use: comboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex; In any case, I tried and the result is the same. comboBox1.SelectedIndex remains -1. I believe there is an event race someware.

Comment: If you think it's a race condition then try `BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(stringValue); });` That should fix it if a race really is the problem because the setter will be placed at the end of the message queue..

Comment: The point of my answer is that calling `comboBox1.FindStringExact(stringValue)` doesn't _set_ anything. The code your show in the body of your post doesn't _set_ anything. In the words of @KlausGütter "It would be much clearer if you showed your real code instead of just quoting one line and merely describing the rest." Plz consider an edit.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, there was an events race. I handled both comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted and also comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged. Assigning the value to comboBox1.SelectedIndex in comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted raised the
comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event which altered it again. The statements are all correct. The inner logic of my application was wrong.